# Serialize Circular Reference with Newtonsoft Json

Tags: c#, serialization, json.net, deserialization

The entity which I am trying to serialize and de-serialize:

```
public class Car
{
    public string Model { get; set; }
    public DateTime Year { get; set; }
    public List<string> Features { get; set; }

    private Car _car;
    public Car Car1
    {
        get
        {
            return _car != null ? _car : new Car();
        }
        set
        {
            _car = value;
        }
    }
}
```

I am using Newtonsoft Json library to serialize and De-serialize above entity.
I can't ignore any property while serialize and De-serialize this entity.

While serializing about entity straight away throws StackOverflow exception.

```
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(car)
```

Most of other places its mentioned about using the below solution, but non of them is working for me.

```
var _jsonSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings()
{
    TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto,
    ConstructorHandling = ConstructorHandling.AllowNonPublicDefaultConstructor,
    PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects,
    ObjectCreationHandling = ObjectCreationHandling.Auto
};

var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects
};

settings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Serialize;

var serialize = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(car, _jsonSettings);

or

var serialize = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(car, settings);
```

I know issue is with this property

```
private Car _car;
    public Car Car1
    {
        get
        {
            return _car != null ? _car : new Car();
        }
        set
        {
            _car = value;
        }
    }
```

but i can't get rid of it for now.

**Modified Question:**

```
public interface IEntity
    {
        int Id { get; set; }
    }
    public class Base1 : IEntity
    {
        public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    }
public class Car : Base1
    {//same properties as defined above in above Car class + below property
        private int _carId;
        public int CarId
        {
            get { return _carId; }
            set { _carId = value; Id = value; }
        }
    }

            var car = new Car();
            car.Model = "Amaze";
            car.Year = new DateTime(2016, 1, 1);
            car.Features = new List<string> { "Light", "1", "2" };
            car.CarId = 1;
```

Here Id of base class will always be zero and derived always set non zero value.
Will it possible to write custom converter (by checking if Property Id has value zero then don't serialize that property further (Car1 property)?)
Any suggestions, how to achieve this?

Comment: Maybe be a typo, but in the the code above you are using _jsonSettings, the settings variable has the loop handling flag. I believe that is what you are after. In other words, try changing to: var serialize = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(car, settings);

Comment: So your Car has a Car1, that has a Car1, that has a Car1, that... Are you sure that your class does what you want it to do?

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are experiencing this is issue is two-fold:

```
return _car != null ? _car : new Car();
```

This is returning a new instance every time if the value of `_car` is `null`, which sends the serializer into an infinite traversal that results in an overflow.

You need to rethink your design. You should be assigning the new instance to the internal variable or you will lose the reference and continue to have `null`:

```
public Car Car1
{
    get
    {
        if(_car == null)
            _car = new Car();
        return _car;
    }
    set
    {
        _car = value;
    }
}
```

This automatic initialization however will continue to be a problem because there will always be a value to serialize. If no object is present, the value should be `null` which will allow the serializer to do its job and reach the end of the object graph.

Comment: Yes. I know about where is the issue. but its really difficult to re-think of this design again and make it correct. That's why i have asked if there is any work around way to make it work.

Comment: @Gopu_Tunas: Think about this for a minute. This is what the serializer is doing because there is always a value for the property. If the serializer stops at some point, you will lose information. If it doesn't it will go forever: (pseudocode) `Serialize(car) => SerializeInternalProperty(car); => SerializeInternalProperty(car); => SerializeInternalProperty(car); => SerializeInternalProperty(car); => SerializeInternalProperty(car);... eternity`. How in the world are you going to "fix" this?

Comment: @Gopu_Tunas I am not sure why you would ever want to have the throw away car scenario that you are creating, but you could get the serializer working if you were willing to set the MaxDepth setting for the serializer.

Comment: @peter.edwards: As I mentioned, he would lose information and defeat the purpose of serializing in the first place but you are correct.

Comment: Note that this is not the same as having a reference to an **existing** object. That is an entirely different matter. In this particular case, you are creating new ones.

Comment: @peter.edwards  Setting max depth is also not solving problem. To limit depth, i have posted new modified question.

Comment: @Gopu_Tunas: You are misunderstanding serialization. Please read my answer again. Your modified version still has the same issue because you are trying to selectively serialize stuff. You need to rethink your design. Serialization is meant to be a representation of your object graph so it doesn't make sense to selectively leave stuff out with custom serializers. The whole idea is that you want to be able to **materialize** back the exact same [graph of] object[s].